# How to bind power button to choice what I want

Tags: release-loki, power

I don't know if when can, but I would like when I press Power Button to ask me my choice (shutdown/reboot/cancel).

I search on dconf but there is no value for choice.

Is it possible ?

sorry for my english !

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the power button by opening System Settings -> Power and making your selection from the dropdown labeled "Power button"

[image: Picture of System Settings]

There is not currently an option to show the end session dialog. This is not something that is provided by the upstream software component that elementary OS uses for this feature.